# search webtext for each word in a list

Tags: python, list, text-mining

I have to write code that collects text from a website chosen by the User and will search this text for three selected words. It will then have to output each word and the number of times it appears on the site.

```
My attempt at writing this program leaves me with an output that tells me that 0 of the words listed are present on the webtext even when I know they do appear. Does anyone have an idea as to how to make it work?
import requests

def main():

    Asentence="This,is,a,sentence,of,some,kind!"
    print(type(Asentence))
    print(Asentence)
    ListOfWords=Asentence.split(",")
    print(type(ListOfWords))
    print(ListOfWords)
    print(ListOfWords[0])
    print(ListOfWords[-1])
    print(ListOfWords[3])

    SomeOtherList=["Sally", "Fred"]
    print(type(SomeOtherList))
    print(SomeOtherList)
    print(SomeOtherList[0])

    for thing in SomeOtherList:
        print(thing)

    n= eval(input("How many websites would you like to enter? :"))
    while n > 0:
        Word()
        n=n-1  



#------------------------------------------   
def Word():   
    answer=input("please enter the websites to examine in the http format ")

    response=requests.get(answer)
    txt = response.text
    print(txt)
    mywords=Firstpart(list)
    num=FindAWord(txt,mywords)
    print("There are", num, "words called",mywords)

#----------------------------------------    
def FindAWord(TheWebText,word):

    print(TheWebText)
    print(type(TheWebText))
    MyList=TheWebText.split(sep=" ")
    print(MyList[0:100])
    count=0
    for item in MyList:
        if(item==word in Firstpart(list)):
            print(item)
            count=count+1

    return count

#----------------------------------

def Firstpart(list):
 wordchoice=[]
 firstword=input("Please enter the first word you would like to look for")
 wordchoice.append(firstword)  
 secondword=input("Please enter the second word you would like to look for")
 wordchoice.append(secondword) 
 thirdword=input("Please enter the third word you would like to look for")
 wordchoice.append(thirdword)
 return wordchoice


main()

Thank you so much in advance.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Counter from the collections module to help you out.

```
import requests
from collections import Counter
def main():
    url = input('Please enter the url to the website you want to search: ')
    if not 'http' in url:
        url = 'http://' + url

    words = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        words.append(input('Please enter word number {}: '.format(i)))

    resp = requests.get(url)
    counter = Counter(resp.text.split())
    for word in words:
        print(word, 'found', counter[word], 'times')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Joakim gave [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42962445/1079129) that helps making your code easier to read and understand but I'll provide you a reason why it doesn't work in the first place.

In your `Word()` function your variable `mywords` is a list of user-inputted words. When you pass that to the `FindAWord` function, you are giving a list instead of a single word. Then when you compare `if(item == word)` (there really shouldn't be `in FirstPart(list)` in that line), you are checking if a single word is equal to a list.

You could fix that part by doing:

```
def Word():   
    answer=input("please enter the websites to examine in the http format ")

    response=requests.get(answer)
    txt = response.text
    print(txt)
    mywords=Firstpart(list)
    for word in mywords:
        num=FindAWord(txt,word)
        print("There are", num, "words called",word)

def FindAWord(TheWebText,word):
    print(TheWebText)
    print(type(TheWebText))
    MyList=TheWebText.split(sep=" ")
    print(MyList[0:100])
    count=0
    for item in MyList:
        if(item==word):
            print(item)
            count=count+1
    return count
```

You should really focus on making your variable names more descriptive to help you (and others) reading the code understand it easier. As you can see, you named the parameter in `FindAWord` a `word` which is singular and gives the impression that it is a single word. Instead, it was a list of words. If it would have been `users_words` or something, you would have immediately seen that something is wrong in `if(item == users_words)`.